# Thinking Sphinx: Missing Attribute for Foreign Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I know a very, very similar question has been asked before. The hackish solution to that question doesn't work if I want to chain in more scopes, so I'm asking again here, with a bit more information as to where the issue is coming from.

```
# Relevant code only...
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues
  has_many :articles, :through => :issues
end

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publication
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  define_index do
    has issue(:publication_id), :as => :publication_id
  end
end
```

Therefore, I'd expect the following code to work:

```
Publication.first.articles.search 'foobar'
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Missing Attribute for Foreign Key publication_id
    from /home/matchu/rails/torch/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/has_many_association.rb:18:in `search'
```

This seems to imply that the publication_id attribute that I specifically set does not exist. However, it does.

```
Article.search :with => {:publication_id => 1}
```

So, I suppose I can just use that syntax, even though it's significantly less pretty. Making this question not particularly urgent. But I definitely am curious as to why this occurs. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain (without getting stuck into the code - it's late where I am at the moment) that you're right, it should work how you have it set up. I assume it's an issue with assumptions on has_many, and not expecting a has_many :through.

If you could create [an issue on GitHub](http://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/issues), that'll help remind me to investigate further.

Cheers

Comment: To future readers: Pat fixed the issue, and thus solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I stumbled upon this looking for a solution to why my index was throwing the same error; I wasn't indexing the association of `Client`, so adding `has client(:client_id), as: :client_id` to my index worked (as the above issue has long been resolved in TS). Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what is in your Publication model, but can you even call Publication.first.articles? Thinking sphinx can't do anything with relationships unless you define them first in active_record:

```
# in Publication.rb
has_many :articles, :through => :issues
```

Searching directly on Article works, but only because you are making sphinx index the issue's publication_id, it doesn't create any relationships in active record.

Comment: Oh, I knew I failed somewhere. I was tired and put the Publication model's code into Issue. Now it all looks like nonsense. I'll have it edited in a minute.

Comment: Edits have been made. Now it's not total nonsense anymore :)